# Implement Single Sign On SAML strategy | Microsoft Azure AD

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, azure-active-directory, saml

I am new to this field and have a lot of confusions, I have to Implement Single Sign On SAML strategy with ReactJS application where it's back-end is node express using Microsoft Azure AD as the IDP?

Please share your thoughts.

Thank you

Comment: Please check this it may help you : https://medium.com/brightlab-techblog/implement-single-sign-on-saml-strategy-with-node-js-passport-js-e8b01ff79cc3

Comment: I tried all of these, but it didn't work with Microsoft Azure AD, I got an infinite loop in the callback function

Comment: Please edit your question where you finding difficulties to execute.